# Remove " and ' that do not have closing tags

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have sentences that I am trying to fill upp the missing tags.

This is importend as I am building a library and need the tags to be closed as it should be.

here is some text example

```
"When the parents of the other boys arrived, things escalated quickly. Seeing their boys broken and unconscious in a foreign house, stinking of their own feces and urines, they demanded for an explanation.

They were all long-time friends, so it was easy for Raaz making them calm down enough to have a civil conversation.

"You" Raaz ordered the nameless one "explain what you did."
```

The above text is missing `"` I would simple like to remove it or close it.

But removing the first `"` is better as closing it is simple not right as I would not know where to add the closing `"`

Right now I am simple validating with the below code which I would like to modify so that it could remove those tags that do not have closing tags

```js
tokensValidations = [] as string[];
validate(fullText: string) {
    ['"', "'"].forEach((x) => {
      const tokens = [...fullText.matchAll(new RegExp(`\\${x}`, 'gmi'))]
        .map((a) => {
          if (a.index == undefined ) return undefined;

          const ch1 = fullText.charAt(a.index - 1);
          const ch2 = fullText.charAt(a.index + 1);

          if (this.isWordOrNumber(ch1) && (this.isWordOrNumber(ch2) || [")", "]"].includes(ch2))) {
            this.exceptionTokens.push({ token: a.toString(), index: a.index, ch1, ch2 });
            return undefined;
          }
          return a;
        })
        .filter((x) => x !== undefined);
      // if all tags are present
      if (tokens.length % 2 === 0) {
          this.tokensValidations.push(x); 
      }
    });
  }
```

Any idea how I could identify those tags that are missing the closing tags?

Comment: Does a quoted string occupy at most one paragraph, or can it span over multiple paragraphs? The former is easier to manage.

Comment: Also, it's tricky with single quotes, such as: 'I am hungry,' O'Connor said.